# What are the ~ds and ~d directories for and why do they resolve to /var/empty?

Tags: terminal, finder, filesystem

I stumbled across two strange filesystem objects named `~d` and `~ds` which look like folders/directories, but don't behave like regular folders/directories and point to `/var/empty`:

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/brenarth/testdir
bash-3.2$ ls -a
.   ..
bash-3.2$ file ~d
/var/empty: directory
bash-3.2$ file ~ds
/var/empty: directory
```

They seem to be accessible from anywhere in MacOS, much like the ~ reference to the current user's home folder e.g.

[image: Finder window showing ~d resolving to private/var/empty]

I haven't been able to find any reference to them online. Can anyone enlighten me as to their purpose?

Comment: Where are you seeing those “files?”  You listed the directory and it only showed `.` and `..` which refer to “current directory” and “parent directory” respectively. Also, if you’re in Bash/Zsh,  the tilde expands to the `HOME` variable.  So, typing `cd ~` it us the same as `cd $HOME` which is the same as `cd /Users/username`

Comment: `~somename` is shell shorthand for "somename's home directory". It sounds like you have accounts on your system named "d" and "ds" without actual home directories, so /var/empty is used as a placeholder.

Comment: As @GordonDavisson says. Use Directory Utility to see all the "users" you have (I have 124).  I don't have d or ds, but there are lots of system or app "users" on my Mac with home directory /var/empty.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson. First time I've come across the ~somename shorthand. Sure enough both d and ds show up as users. Mystery solved.